# error wihle declaring a variable using template

Tags: c++, caffe, pycaffe

To make a debug process easier, I decided to declare a global variable which is a pointer to a class object and use the global pointer to access any lower class variables.  The class is defined using template. At some point when the class object is constructed, I could assign the global pointer and use it somewhere else.
In my case, I tried to add a variable type Net (this is for py-faster-rcnn code).

```
    namespace caffe {
    ...
        int glb_layer_id;
        template <typename Dtype>
        shared_ptr<Net<Dtype>> glb_Net;

        template <typename Dtype>
        void Net<Dtype>::Init(const NetParameter& in_param) {
            ...
        }
```

Adding `int glb_layer_id` was no problem and I could use the variable somewhere else. But when I add a variable glb_Net, I had a compile error below.

ckim@stph45:~/Neuro/py-faster-rcnn.org] !make
make -C caffe-fast-rcnn/
make: Entering directory `/home/ckim/Neuro/py-faster-rcnn.org/caffe-fast-rcnn'
CXX src/caffe/net.cpp
src/caffe/net.cpp:41: error: template declaration of 'caffe::Net<Dtype>* caffe::glb_Net'
src/caffe/net.cpp: In member function 'void caffe::Net<Dtype>::Init(const caffe::NetParameter&)':
src/caffe/net.cpp:75: error: 'glb_Net' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [.build_debug/src/caffe/net.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory`/home/ckim/Neuro/py-faster-rcnn.org/caffe-fast-rcnn'

The class `Net` was originally defined using template  so I have to use the same template for the Net variable. But as can be see, there is an error. What is the problem? Any help appreciated. (By the way, in Caffe, I also want to know how I can access the Net variable from a layer inside the Net).

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a shared_ptr variable is done without specifying the 'template' keyword.
Instead of declaring

```
template <typename Dtype> shared_ptr<Net<Dtype>> glb_Net;
```

You should have declared glb_Net as:

```
#include <Dtype.h>
#include <Net.h>
shared_ptr<Net<Dtype>> glb_Net;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that, using `shared_prt<Net<Dtype>> glb_Net;` I got errors like this : `src/caffe/net.cpp:40: error: 'Dtype' was not declared in this scope
src/caffe/net.cpp:40: warning: '>>' operator will be treated as two right angle brackets in C++0x
src/caffe/net.cpp:40: warning: suggest parentheses around '>>' expression
src/caffe/net.cpp:40: error: 'glb_Net' was not declared in this scope
src/caffe/net.cpp:40: error: template argument 1 is invalid
src/caffe/net.cpp:40: error: template argument 1 is invalid` any idea?

Comment: I added the proper includes to my answer. Maybe you should include a small sample application so that we could correct all the issues. Your example above was just a snippet, so we could not tell everything that is missing from it.

Comment: in namespace caffe, I see `typedef float Dtype;` and I included net.hpp. This is a part of complex codes so I would better make a simple example. I'm in the middle of fixing a bug so I'll do it sometime later. thanks.

Comment: For dbg1.hpp file : #include "caffe/net.hpp"

extern int glb_layer_id;
template <typename Dtype>
extern shared_ptr< Net<Dtype> > glb_Net_ptr;
./include/caffe/dbg1.hpp:5: error: expected initializer before '<' token
./include/caffe/dbg1.hpp:8: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type
./include/caffe/dbg1.hpp:8: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token